# Share aliases and PATH setting between zsh and bash

Tags: shell, bash, zsh, path, alias

The shell that I normally use is `zsh`. I have several aliases to enable color in some programs such as `ls` and `grep`. I've also set my custom path so that I can execute programs in non-standard place (such as in `~/bin/`).

I [won't change root's shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2640/250) to `zsh`, but I would like to share these setting so that root can have it as well. I find out that `zsh` is not sourcing `/etc/profile`. I can source it in `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, but I would like some other more "proper" way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd create a file `/etc/commonprofile` and source it in both `/etc/profile` and `/etc/zsh/zprofile`. This gives you the opportunity to share common settings and still use `bash` respectively `zsh` specific settings and syntax in `/etc/profile` respectively `zprofile`.

Comment: among other good answers I think this one suits me the best, relatively simple and "clean"

Comment: what do you mean by "source it" ?

Comment: @Hlung For loading the shell profile explicility, here the 'source /path/to/.shell_profile' comes. See man page on 'source'.

Answer (score 19):

Zsh has an sh compatibility mode which will let it execute POSIX sh code and some bash extensions. As long as you don't use bash features that zsh doesn't have (with the same syntax), you can have the same file sourced by both shells. Use the `emulate` built-in to put zsh in compatibility mode; with the `-L` option, the emulation is local to the enclosing function (not the enclosing sourced script).

```
source_sh () {
  emulate -LR sh
  . "$@"
}
```

For things like environment variables, you can use `source_sh /etc/profile` in `/etc/zprofile` and `source_sh ~/.profile` in `~/.zprofile`, since the profile files aren't likely to use bash-specific features.

For things like aliases and function definitions, since the shell rc files are likely to contain a lot of things that can't be shared (prompt, key bindings, completion settings, …), use a file like `~/.sh_aliases` that is sourced in `~/.bashrc` and `source_sh`'d in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: There should be a way to say "automatically upvote all answers by Gilles". This would save me quite some time. No really, your answers rock. Always accurate, well written and comprehensive.

Comment: @fschmitt: I agree. And you can see it's not even edited! This hint provided here is really good.

Comment: Better to source in the respective env files imo. Eg.. Zshenv or  bash_env

Comment: @RichieHH Despite their names, the `*env` scripts are not a good place to set environment variables, because they are read by every script — but only scripts run by that particular shell. So if a program runs a script and expects it to have a certain environment, it might stop working, if your `*env` script happens to modify a variable that the program cares about.

Answer (score 4):

What about a simple symlink?

`ln -s /etc/profile /etc/zsh/zprofile`

You can also append something like this if you need some conditional initialization:

```
#Determine our shell without using $SHELL, which may lie
shell="sh"
if test -f /proc/mounts; then
   case $(/bin/ls -l /proc/$$/exe) in
        *bash) shell=bash ;;
        *dash) shell=dash ;;
        *ash)  shell=ash ;;
        *ksh)  shell=ksh ;;
        *zsh)  shell=zsh ;;
    esac
fi
```

Comment: Hmm but I don't think this will be any cleaner than sourcing it. Is there a file that both zsh and bash will read?

Comment: what makes you think that sourcing or creating a symlink is not a "clean" solution?

Comment: I just meant to say if needed, I'd like to source the file rather than to manage the symlink. I don't want to create a lot of dependency between files.

Comment: A more portable alternative to `/bin/ls -l /proc/$$/exe` is `ps -o comm= -p $$`. This isn't fully reliable because some shells behave differently depending on how they were invoked; in practice simply testing `$0` in `.profile` is likely to be a better indication. But most shells that offer useful features (bash, ksh, zsh) can be simply recognized (and their version identified, which is a big plus) by testing some variables: `$BASH`, `$BASH_VERSION`, `$BASH_VERSINFO`; `$KSH_VERSION`, `${.sh.version}`; `$ZSH_VERSION`.

Comment: echox, your case statement does not correctly detect zsh4  


    #Determine our shell without using $SHELL, which may lie  

    shell="sh"  
    if test -f /proc/mounts; then  
        case $(/bin/ls -l /proc/$$/exe) in  
            *bash) shell=bash ;;  
            *dash) shell=dash ;;  
            *ash)  shell=ash ;;  
            *ksh)  shell=ksh ;;  
            *zsh*) shell=zsh ;; #matches zsh4  
        esac  
    fi

Answer (score 0):

As regards variables, I have the impression that you are missing modules & modulefiles [1].
Once you start doing so, it will be easy to create common profiles for various shells (incl. bash & zsh), python, perl and even more environments, all from the convenience of a single module file.

It is also possible to define aliases in the same way; however, you will quickly find that aliases do not get inherited very well between successive shells and may need workarounds.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_(software)