# How could I reach root after switching from bash to zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, login, root

It's very weird that after switching to zsh from bash, I can't access root.

I normally use 'su' to login as root after I login as a normal user (username is `normalusername`) with less privileges. And it was always nice. But after switching root shell from bash to zsh, when I try to login via su, I got:

```
normalusername@(none):~$ su
Password: (enter the correct password)
Cannot execute zsh: No such file or directory
```

When I access root directly via ssh from my Mac, I got:

```
localhost:~ myname$ ssh -lroot 106.186.120.20
root@106.186.120.20's password: (enter the correct/incorrect password)
Permission denied, please try again.
```

No matter whether I entered the correct password, it comes again and again.

So I intentionally entered a wrong password with "su" from a normal user, I got:

```
normalusername@(none):~$ su
Password: (entered a wrong password and pressed enter)
(pressed enter)
su: Authentication failure
```

After entering the incorrect password I didn't see anything, I typed <kbd>enter</kbd> twice and then got the `su: Authentication failure` result.

I tried for many times and the conclusion is:

1. If I enter the correct password, it will tell me that "Cannot execute zsh: No such file or directory"
2. If I enter the incorrect password, it will not showing up anything until I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> for 2-6 times.

It seems to be an indication that I didn't just forget the "correct password". But how can I access root anyway?

The entry in `/etc/passwd` is

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:zsh
```

Comment: It looks like you have specified the new shell incorrectly. Did you enter the full path to zsh when you changed it?

Comment: @jimmij It's `root:x:0:0:root:/root:zsh` so it should be `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh` instead, right? How could I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo `chsh` allows you to change a user's shell. If you can't use it, or can't get permissions to, try to edit `/etc/passwd` directly. You may need `sudo` at some point ;)

Comment: Just entered `sudo vim /etc/passwd` to edit it, before I was asked to enter a password, I got `sudo: unable to resolve host (none)` then I was prompted to enter the password for my current user. I entered and then I got this: `normalusername is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: Use `sh -s /bin/bash`, then fix the problem.

Comment: re `sudo` on some systems being in group `sudo` will allow you to use sudo with full privileges. I would recommend `sudo` over `su`.

Comment: Let this be a lesson for all about glancing around for and respecting any statements like "actually, you should [some seemingly unimportant nit-picky thing like 'always use absolute paths when setting the shell']".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try: `cd /usr/bin; su`.
Since you didn't give an absolute path to zsh. `su` is checking the `PWD`. changing to the directory `zsh` exists in will work on some systems.
an example:

```
% su
Password:
su: zsh: No such file or directory
% cd /usr/local/bin
% su
Password:
# print $OSTYPE
freebsd10.0
#
```

Comment: And you won't ever have to use it again, because you are going to use absolute paths to the login shells right? :}

Answer (score 8):

Your entry in `/etc/passwd` is

> ```
> root:x:0:0:root:/root:zsh
> ```

This is an invalid entry: the shell must be a full path to an executable, the login program does not perform $PATH lookup.

You won't be able to log into the root account by normal means. You can use sudo to invoke a command, e.g. `sudo vipw`, if your account has sudo permissions. This is the only common method to bypass the login shell setting in the target account.

If you aren't a sudoer, you've probably locked yourself out of the root account. You'll need console access to repair the system. Boot in single user mode (see [How do I run a command as the system administrator (root)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root/3064#3064)) and edit `/etc/passwd` to contain

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
```

(with the correct path for zsh on your system).

Some administrators set up a [toor account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/is-it-bad-practice-to-set-roots-shell-to-something-other-than-the-default/2644#2644) with UID 0 but a different shell (typically a statically linked binary such as [sash](http://members.tip.net.au/~dbell/_), to allow root to log in even in case of a misconfiguration such as this one (the most common misconfiguration is a broken shared library in the normal shell).

To avoid such issues in the future, use the `chsh` command to change a user's shell, rather than editing `/etc/passwd` directly. And if you must edit `/etc/passwd` or some other file that is involved in gaining root access, keep a root shell open in a terminal and don't close it until you've verified that you can still log in as root.

Answer (score 4):

- Check your current shell with

  ```
  grep '^root:' /etc/passwd
  ```

  you should see at the end of the line full path to shell used by root user, like `/bin/zsh`. Then check if the path is not misspelled, file exists and has proper permissions set (`r`ead and e`x`ecute).
- If path was not correct then check where your `zsh` executable is placed with

  ```
  type zsh
  ```
- After that `su` to root using the correct shell path, e.g. in case of `/bin/zsh`:

  ```
  su -s /bin/zsh -
  ```
- Lastly run `chsh` to change default shell to `/bin/zsh`

Comment: I checked the file passwd and noticed it's `root:x:0:0:root:/root:zsh` and after I checked with `type zsh` I got `zsh is /usr/bin/zsh`. So I use `su -s /usr/bin/zsh` but the same trouble happened. I was asked to enter the password and If I enter the correct one, I got a `Cannot execute zsh: No such file or directory` error

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo what does `ls -l /usr/bin/zsh` show?

Comment: result: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Dec 26 06:53 /usr/bin/zsh -> /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin`

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo and `ls -l /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin`?

Comment: What's the difference between `su -s /usr/bin/zsh` and `su -s /usr/bin/zsh -` ?

Comment: @PM2Ring basically it sets all environment variables for login user, from manual: `argument - may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.` Compare for example `echo $PATH` with and without `-` argument.

Comment: @jimmij So would leaving out the final `-` have caused the error mentioned in the 1st comment?

Comment: @PM2Ring Very unlikely. `su` without `-` should work fine, it just leaves (do not set) some variables, perhaps better example is `export LC_ALL=C` and then compare `su` or `su -` to another user. OP on the other hand seems to have some problem with (broken?) link or file permission.

Comment: @jimmij `ls -l /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin` got -> `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 26 06:53 /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin -> /bin/zsh4`

Comment: @jimmij `su -s /usr/bin/zsh` and `su -s /usr/bin/zsh -` got the exact same result.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo and what about `ls -l /bin/zsh4`?

Comment: @jimmij result: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 696880 Feb 28  2012 /bin/zsh4`

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Try to pass `/bin/zsh4` to `su` directly. Also what happens when you just run `zsh`, is it ok?

Comment: @jimmij did you mean `su /bin/zsh4`? It got `No passwd entry for user '/bin/zsh4'` and I wasn't promoted to enter any password

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Yes, but with `-s` option. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19978/discussion-between-jimmij-and-aw-qirui-guo).