# Switched from bash to zsh and now I can't login as root

Tags: zsh, su, oh-my-zsh

I have changed my shell from bash to zsh and set it as default in Ubuntu 20.10 and now every time I run the command su i get this:

```
su
Password: (entered correct password)
su: Authentication failure
```

Does Anyone knows why?

Comment: does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177343/how-could-i-reach-root-after-switching-from-bash-to-zsh?rq=1

Comment: Did you change _your_ shell, or did you change root's shell? Note that there is never a reason to change root's login shell, on account of you shouldn't need to log in as root very often.