# sudo su in bash error "Cannot execute help: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, root

I installed zsh and changed root shell /bin/bash to /usr/bin/zsh. Then I rebooted and typed sudo su. It said "Cannot execute help: No such file or directory". So, I typed sudo bash. However, when I typed "echo $SHELL", it said the root shell is 'help'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message `Cannot execute help: No such file or directory` indicates that root's login shell has been set to `help` rather than to a valid shell.

You may fix this by issuing the correct `chsh` command:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

or by editing root's login record in `/etc/passwd`.  *This file must be edited with `vipw`* (never ever directly):

```
sudo vipw
```

On most Linux systems, root's entry in the file that opens up in the editor when you use `vipw` should look something like

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

You should make sure that the last `:`-delimited field is the correct path to the login shell for root on your system, and change it in the editor if it's not.  Then save the file and exit.

---

Note that there is absolutely *no* benefit in changing the login shell of root, as you should not find yourself logging in as root or using an interactive root shell for any lengths of time.

Any administrational tasks that you may need to perform on the system may be performed using `sudo` followed by the command that you need to execute.

There is additionally no need to use `su` with `sudo`.  This is discussed in the answers to the question [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)

Comment: So the questioner _did not_ change the superuser's login shell to the Z shell as the question claims, but at one point ran `chsh -s help` instead of `chsh --help`.  For more on the subject of changing the superuser's login shell, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/ .

Comment: I had same problem but instead of help, it was showing virsh: No such file or directory.

Comment: But I saw history , I didnt  write some chsh command, I did write csh then virsh, I was just exploring different shell

Comment: But I saw history , I didnt  write some chsh command, I did write csh then virsh, I was just exploring different shell