# cannot use sudo -i

Tags: sudo, root

When I try to log in as root, it always shows the error like this. I tried to use apt install sudo and apt-get update but nothing has changed

[image]

Comment: Can you check some files for root user as mentioned in the manual.
 `Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile, .bash_profile or .login will be read by the shell.`

Comment: ok, how to run that?

Comment: `getent passwd root`.  The last `:`-delimited item in the list return from that command is the login shell for the root user. If it says `johny` then you have set the login shell of the root user to `johny` and this would be why you can't log in as root. Also, please never post images of text.

Comment: Run `type sudo` if there is some alias or function defined...

Comment: it says sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo), what does that mean?

Comment: @Kusalananda how do I fix that?

Comment: Related: [sudo su in bash error "Cannot execute help: No such file or directory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422712/sudo-su-in-bash-error-cannot-execute-help-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, it finally works